# Processing JSON in Objective C

Tags: ios, xcode, arrays, json, xcode4

How can I go about pulling a single rating value out of a JSON dictionary? The rating value resides only in the parent JSON dictionary (it is not nested). My code is here:

```
- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
  NSDictionary *allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];

  for (NSDictionary *diction in allDataDictionary)
  {
    NSString *rating = [diction objectForKey:@"rating"];
    [array addObject:rating];
  }

  [[self myTableView] reloadData];
}
```

Secondly, how can I make an If statement to convert the rating value to an `NSString` for it to appear on the iPhone simulator?

Comment: NSLog is your friend.  Log the output of the JSON parser and see what it looks like.  (The "JSON script" you show above is not valid JSON, so it's hard to guess what you actually have.)

Comment: BTW, if, as you say, the data "is not nested", why are you looking for nested dictionaries inside the main dictionary?)  (If it is, indeed, a dictionary and not an array.)

Comment: Thanks! I am not looking for any nested dictionaries inside the main. I just want that one value.

Comment: "Your" code (the code you blindly copied from somewhere) is attempting to find dictionaries in an outer dictionary.  Whether you're "looking" for that or not.

Comment: Well I'm new to this, so I'm experimenting and haven't done anything with JSON before until now. I managed to pull some values out of the code to the iPhone simulator itself. I'm just trying to figure out now why it seems as though it crashes when I want it to pull small values like restaurant ratings out. Values like names and urls it successfully displays on the iPhone simulator.

Comment: *Once again*, use NSLog to dump the output from the parser.  Study the output until you *UNDERSTAND* it.  NSArrays are shown with `()` brackets and NSDictionaries are shown with `{}` brackets.  Once you know what you have, "peel the onion" to get to the data you're after.

Comment: Thank you for your patience..... I realize newbies are frustrating for you experts.

Comment: @greg23af, Try this `NSArray *array = [allDataDictionary valueForKey:@"rating"];` Does that resolve your issue?

Comment: I actually managed to make this work already, but thank you! The only piece I am now stuck on is trying to make an IF statement to convert the rating value to an NSString in the actual table cell entry. Apparently, every other value will post to the iPhone simulator except "rating," because it isn't identified as a string I am assuming.

Comment: I imagine I need something like the following: if ([[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] class] == [NSNumber class]) {cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];}

Comment: If it is an NSNumber, you can use `[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue];`. Can you please add that to the question with required details. We can resolve it.

Comment: I'm unsure, still working on it. Seems to work, but in the end the rating value doesn't post to simulator, it crashes, and I get: '-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9048b80'

Comment: Can you post the code which is crashing in the question?

Comment: Did it! I was screwing around with a conditional to say IF the string contains numbers to convert it to string, else it's just string, but I did away with it and only used     cell.textLabel.text = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue]. The rating value posted! Thank you thank you.

Comment: @greg23af, I have added as an answer. There was one more mistake with your if condition as well. You should use isKindOfClass to check class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fetch all the ratings objects from the dictionary, you can use:

```
NSArray *array = [allDataDictionary valueForKey:@"rating"];
```

This depends on the JSON representation and the structure of your data set.

For the second issue, if this object is an `NSNumber`, you can try this:

```
if ([[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
     cell.textLabel.text = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue];
}
```

Note that you have to use `isKindOfClass` method to check for the class and `stringValue` to convert to string.